# Rails starts server but not console - No such file or director @ dir_s_chdir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I started a new repo in ~/documents/forecasts that seems to behave well in general. Bundle works, the server starts, etc. However, when I run `rails c`, it returns:

```
➜  forecasts git:(master) ✗ rails c
/Users/z/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.1/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:178:in `chdir': No such file or directory @ dir_s_chdir - /Users/z/forecasts (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /Users/z/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.1/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:178:in `serve'
    from /Users/z/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.1/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
    from /Users/z/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.1/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
    from /Users/z/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.1/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
    from /Users/z/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.1/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/Users/z/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from <internal:/Users/z/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

It seems to refer to a location that doesn't exist and never existed (/Users/z/forecasts). I'm not sure how to bypass this error.

Comment: looks like your spring gem got downloaded into path `/Users/z/.rvm/.......` Were you playing around with RVM or have multiple versions of ruby on your machine? Perhaps it might be helpful to reinstall the spring dependencies at your ideal location?

Comment: @CarlsBad505 I'm not sure TBH - I also don't have a preference about where the stuff is as long as it's set up correctly. If reinstalling spring dependencies at my location is the correct thing to do, how do I do it? If the current location is fine, how do I solve the error?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your issue is quite broad and its hard to diagnose, while not understanding your initial installation process. But you have a few options available to you. With Rails 6, spring comes preloaded by default and is used for to speed up your development environment, read more here: https://github.com/rails/spring

**Option 1:** `gem uninstall spring`
You can just live without it, but I'm not sure you want to do that if you're going to be doing heavy development on your app.

**Option 2:** Reinstall:
Somehow it got installed at a ghost path. So what you want to do is go nuke it out of that path like `rm -f` it. The run `bundle install` again at the root of your application to get it back

If I had to guess, at some point in your past you had the app or maybe a different Rails app at that location `/Users/z/forecasts` and again - not sure what happened in the past, but smells like these dependencies got crossed up. Especially if you're saying that path is unrecognizable to you.

Hope this helps get you on the right path at least.

UPDATE: Sorry also forgot to mention, you can also scan your initializers to see if there are some custom configs for Spring that might be causing this.